# editable datagrid with object ({int, double}) in each cell and having arbitrary count of columns

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I am  working on a bill logging module using WPF(MVVM) and SQLite.

I have multiple company names (arbitrary count) e.g. acme soft, cyberways, microcore, solotronics and more..

User will log each and every company's electricity, dg power, xyz etc units consumption on daily basis.
My logging data table in DB looks like:

```
LogDataID,
LogCategory(electricity, dg power, xyz etc),
ConsumedUnits,
Dated,
CompanyID
```

after data processing, iam able to retrieve it in a DataGrid as:
[image: Bill Log Data grid Image]

Now i want to display `ConsumedUnits` only with ***edit*** functionality too. I Have tried lots of stuff like binding datagrid code behind(against mvvm), `DataContextChanged` event and tried to search for the solution but in vain.

I can use `DataGridTemplateColumn` only if count of the companies is fixed, which is not.

So can anybody help me in making this `DataGrid` useful and editable (in accordance to `LogDataID` and the value of `UnitsReading` is 0 by default).

Comment: You can do a few things, 1st keep what you have but change the visibility of the columns until you want to show them.  As for editing, change your consumedunits datagridtemplatecolumn.cellediting template to be what you want it to be such as a TextBox or Rich Text Box.  When user double clicks on that cell the template shows up.  Make sure to use Binding to the itemsource. 2) You can provide a button that opens up a detailed editor for that row item. (usually will be a separate usercontrol)...

Comment: MVVM != no codebehind ("against mvvm").  UI logic belongs in your codebehind.  Create a UserControl that properly handles this situation and use it in your data grid template.

Comment: @JohnPeters how can i use `DataGridTemplateColumn` for arbitrary number of columns in xaml ? and providing seperate popup for edit will make it less user friendly, i need it to be like excel spreadsheet.

Comment: yes @Will i was aware of the fact that code behind can be used for UI logic, but in order to bind the datagrid i have to pass all the data or manuplate the datacontext. And can u give me hint for the UserControl ?

Comment: Arbitrary columns require code behind...   like this   foreach(var arbitrarycolumn in mycollection) MyDatagrid.Columns.Add( new DataGridTemplateColumn(){ Header= arbitrarayColumn.Title .... etc.

Comment: Did you try my suggestion?

Comment: @JohnPeters no, I didn't. Just made a custom pivot datatable function. Code behind bindings were not working for me. Anyways thanks for your concern.